# The difference between 'callback' and 'respond'

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

When you receive a request, you can callback to it or respond to it?

What's the difference?

Comment: I would not use "callback" in this context. I know the word only as a programming term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callback would be when you are *called back*, as in you've already been there once.

For example, a refrigerator repairman might say that he *responded* to a customer's call, where he made a repair, but the next day he got a ***callback*** since the same refrigerator broke down again.  (He then responded to the callback, where he made a second repair.)